# register page with MVC model

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller

I am trying to build a website with a register page with MVC model, but when i clicked a register button to submit, it pointed to the controller but with a blank page. Here's my MVC i've tried so far
View:

```
register.jsp

    <form action="controller" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> Username </td>
            <td><input type ="text" name="uname" size="30"required></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Your email address </td>
            <td><input type ="text" name="mail" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="pass" size="20"required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Please re-type your password</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="p2" size="20"required></td>
        </tr>
        <table>

        <tr>
            <td>Gender</td>
            <td><input type ="radio" value="r1" checked name="Gender">Male</td>
            <td><input type ="radio" value="r2" checked name="Gender">Female</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit"></td>
            <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" name="s5"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

My Model is

```
public class signin extends HttpServlet {


public void register(String uname, String pass, String email) throws SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {

    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "webauth";
    String userName = "root";
    String passWord = "";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, passWord);
    PreparedStatement statement;
    statement = conn.prepareStatement("insert into data(username, email, password)" + " values (?,?,?,?)");
    statement.setString(1,uname );
    statement.setString(2, pass);
    statement.setString(3, email);
    statement.executeUpdate();
    statement.clearParameters();
    statement.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

and my Controller :

```
try {

      String action = request.getParameter("submit");

      if (action.equals("Register")){
            String Uname = request.getParameter("uname");
            String Pword = request.getParameter("pass");
            String Email = request.getParameter("mail");

            boolean check = false;
            try {
                signin signin = new signin();
                check = signin.takeuser(Uname);
                if (check)
                    request.setAttribute("error","This user has already been registered");
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception");
            }
            if (check){
                RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("signin.jsp");
                dispatch.forward(request, response);
            }
            else{
                try{
                    signin signin = new signin();
                    signin.checkLogin(Uname, Email, Pword);
                    response.sendRedirect("registersuccess.jsp");
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Exception");
                }
            }
      }
    } finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a strong feeling we are not talking ASP.NET here.

Comment: sorry, i have edited the tags

Answer (score 0):

e,I think your "Controller" should `extends` HttpServlet..not the "Signin", Or you can modify the form's action ,it's `Signin`. The last,configurate your  `web.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

```
            if (check){
                RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("signin.jsp");
                dispatch.forward(request, response);
            }
            else{
                try{
                    signin signin = new signin();
                    signin.checkLogin(Uname, Email, Pword);
                    response.sendRedirect("registersuccess.jsp");
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Exception");
                }
            }
```

in this code if you consider else part if try block executed successfully then you will be redirected to registersuccess.jsp but if some exception occurs then you are just printing exception but not redirecting anywhere.

This could be a reason like you are getting exception in the mentioned try block so you are not getting redirected anywhere. just check your console is printing "Exception"?

Or better you debug your code so that you can figure out in which block it goes.